# Three-player duel of complete information. Optimal strategy and Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, infinite-games

I have a three-player duel in which players A,B and C pick a time t in the interval [0,1] to fire at a common target and they can only fire once. When player A fires at time t, he will hit with probability t. Similar for player B and C, but they will hit with probability t^2 and t^3 respectively. When a player has fired, their opponents will know and are allowed to fire at a different time than what they initially had in mind. I'm asked to calculate an optimal strategies for all players.

The two-player variant of the game has already been solved by. Say A and B are playing the same duel with two players, then an optimal strategy for A is to fire at a time t such that t = (1 - t^2) and similar for B.

Using the same method as in the two player duel, A should fire at a time t such that t0 = (1-t^2) * 0.682 in which 0.682 is the time t where player A and C should fire if they play a two player duel. A similar equation holds for player B, he fires at a time t1 such that t^2 = (1 - t)0.755^2 in which 0.755 is the time where player B and C should fire if they play a two player duel.

When solving these equations, I find that t0 = 0.507 and t1 = 0.522 which are not equal. This solution is therefore not a Nash equilibrium, because player A could also fire at t = 0.521 for a higher probability of winning.

Is firing at t0 for player A and at t1 for player B an optimal strategy? I thought that an optimal strategy minimizes a players loss their opponents can do and is not necessarily equal to a Nash equilibrium.

Thanks in advance!

To clarify the two-player duel. At any time t, A will hit with probability t and B will hit with probability t^2. The optimal time for both players to fire is when t = (1 - t^2). This is when As probability of hitting and winning is equal to As probability of winning when B fires at time t.

Comment: What is "the same duel with two players"? Is it where A hits with probability $t$ and B hits with probability $t^2,$ or are the probabilities $t^2$ and $t^3,$ or something else? What are the values to each player of each outcome? If B's only concern is whether or not B is hit (with "hit" being the worse outcome), then why wouldn't B gain in the two-player game by firing earlier than A would? And vice versa? A complete statement and step-by-step analysis of the two-player game might be useful here.

Comment: It would be easier to read the question if you used MathJax, especially if you add any more formulas (which should be **edited into the question**, not posted as comments). See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I'm sorry for the sloppy post. The three-player duel becomes a two player duel as soon as one of the players has fired and missed. For example if A fires at t = 1/3 and B and C at t = 1/2 both. Then A would fire first and hit with probability 1/3. With probability 1 - (1/3), B and C continue the game as a two player game and they are allowed to fire at a different time than their initially set t = 1/2.

Comment: It is confusing that you call this a "duel." In a duel, the opponents shoot **at each other.** We may guess from your description of the strategy that a player wins something when they hit the target, and as soon as the target is hit, everyone who has not shot loses their chance to shoot. But what if A and B fire simultaneously and both hit? Does A win the same amount as if only A had hit?

Comment: The player that hits the target first wins and gets +2 ( 1 from each player) and the game is ended. We assume that when two or more players fire at the same time, they flip a fair coin (or roll a fair 3 sided dice) and depending on this flip one of the players will fire slightly earlier than the other(s). If the player that fires slightly earlier misses, the remaining opponents that have not fired yet continue to play.

Comment: So in a two-player game between A and B, if A fires when $t=1-t^2$ (that is, A fires at time $\phi=\frac12(\sqrt5-1)\approx0.618$), B has probability $\frac12\phi^2\approx0.191$ to win by firing at the same time (because B has to win the coin toss with probability $\frac12$ _and_ hit the target with probability $\phi^2$), but B has probability $0.617^2\approx0.381$ to win by firing at time $0.617.$ So why would B wait until time $0.618$ instead of firing at time $0.617$?

Comment: In the case that both players fire at ϕ, player B can win by either winning the coin flip and hitting the shot or by lose the coin flip and by A missing the shot. If A wins the coin flip and misses, which happens with probability $$\frac{1}{2} (1 - \phi)$$, B can switch to firing at $t = 1$.

Comment: I see, you literally did mean something like a coin toss. And whoever "loses" the toss is then allowed to change their firing time. How does this work--each player writes their chosen time secretly and submits it to a referee who tosses the coin if necessary and then announces who should fire first and at at what time? The mechanism you need seems highly counterintuitive to the way you describe it in the question, beginning with the word "duel."

Comment: This could be an interesting question, but notice how so far it's just the two of us discussing it. I hope someone else would contribute if the question were a little better organized and easier to parse.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something else. When you say "complete information," does that mean A, B, and C each knows what time each other player has chosen, and each has the option to make a new choice until they mutually agree on a schedule in which nobody wants to change their own firing time? I don't think that changes the answer but it would imply that the players won't even get to their first shot unless there's an equilibrium.

Comment: With complete information i ment that when a player fires at a time t, the opponents will know and they can change their time of firing. So for example in the two-player game between A and B. If A chooses $t = 1/3$ and B chooses $t = 1/2$, then at time t = 1/3 player A fires. If he misses (with probability 2/3), then player B can change his time of firing. In this case, he will change and fire at $t = 1$, because A can't fire anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to analyze a slightly more general two-player game first.

We consider a family $\mathcal F$ of non-decreasing real-valued functions such that for each function $p$ in the family, $0 \leq p(t) \leq 1$ for all $t$;
$p(t) < p(t')$ whenever $0 \leq t < t' \leq 1$; and $p(1) = 1.$
Each player is associated with one function from this family.

For the two-player game between any two players X and Y,
we have a function $p_X\in\mathcal F$ associated with X,
a function $p_Y\in\mathcal F$ associated with Y, and some number $t_S < 1.$

To play this game, 
players X and Y each secretly chooses a number $t_X,$ $t_Y$ (respectively)
within the range $[t_S, 1].$
Neither knows what number the other has chosen until the numbers are simultaneously announced.
After the numbers $t_X$ are $t_y$ are announced, one of two procedures is followed,
either "X shoots first" or "Y shoots first." If $t_X < t_Y$ then X shoots first;
if $t_Y < t_X$ then Y shoots first; if $t_X = t_Y$ then either X shoots first or Y shoots first with equal probability.

If X shoots first then X wins with probability $p_X(t_X)$ and Y wins with probability $1 - p_X(t_X).$ (In effect, if X does not win, Y is then allowed to choose the number $1$ instead of $t_Y$ and therefore wins with probability $1.$)
If Y shoots first then Y wins with probability $p_Y(t_Y)$ and X wins with probability $1 - p_Y(t_Y).$

So there are only two outcomes to this game: X wins or Y wins. Assume each player wants to maximize their chance of winning.

Let $t_E$ be a time such that $p_X(t_E) + p_Y(t_E) = 1.$
Then if $t_E \geq t_S,$ the combined strategy $t_X=t_Y=t_E,$ so that X wins with probability $p_X(t_E)$ and Y wins with probability $p_Y(t_E),$ is an equilibrium,
because if either player chose a smaller number they would reduce their chance to win,
but if they chose a larger number then the other player could also increase their number (by a lesser amount) and increase their chance to win.

If $t_E < t_S$ then the equilibrium is $t_X=t_Y=t_S,$ because 
$\frac12 p_X(t_S) + \frac12 (1 - p_Y(t_S)) > (1 - p_Y(t_S))$
(the left side being the worst case if X chooses $t_S$ and the right side
being the worst case if X chooses a greater number), so that $t_S$ dominates all other choices for X,
and because $t_S dominates all other choices for Y for similar reasons.

---

For the three-player game, each of the players A, B, and C
is associated with the functions $p_A,$ $p_B,$ and $p_C$ (respectively)
in the family $\mathcal F.$
Players A, B, and C each secretly chooses a number $t_A,$ $t_B,$ $t_C$ (respectively) within the range $[0, 1].$
Then the three numbers are announced and one player is selected to "shoot first."
If one player chose a number smaller than both other players' numbers, that player shoots first;
if there is a "tie" for smallest number then each person choosing that number has an equal chance to shoot first.
Whichever player shoots first wins with probability $p_Z(t_Z),$ 
where $p_Z\in\mathcal F$ is the function associated with that player and $t_Z$ is the number chosen by that player.
If that player does not win, the winner of the three-player game is the winner of a two-player game between the remaining two players with $t_S = t_Z.$

For your particular three players, 
$p_A(t) = t,$ $p_B(t) = t^2,$ and $p_C(t) = t^3,$
so that the equilibrium strategy for a game between A and C is
$t_A=t_C\approx 0.68233$
and for a game between B and C is $t_B=t_C\approx 0.75488$
(provided that the $t_S$ is not greater).
The probability that C wins is only about
$(1 - t_A)0.75488^3$ if A shoots first (with $t_A < 0.75488$)
and only about
$(1 - t_B^2)0.68233^3$ if B shoots first (with $t_B < 0.68233$).

So C should allow A to shoot first if and only if $t_A < 0.569842$
(because then $p_C(t_A) = t_A^3 < (1 - t_A)0.75488^3$)
and should allow B to shoot first if and only if $t_B < 0.591205$
(because then $p_C(t_B) = t_B^3 < (1 - t_B^2)0.68233^3$);
otherwise C would be better off shooting first.

The probability that B wins is about
$(1 - t_A)0.75488^2$ if A shoots first (with $t_A < 0.75488$),
so B should only allow A to shoot first if $t_A < 0.521939,$
because then $$p_B(t_A) = t_A^2 < (1 - t_A)0.75488^2. \tag1$$

But should A set $t_A < 0.521939$?
Suppose $t_A = 0.521$; then A wins with probability $0.521.$
But if $t_A = t_B = 0.521939$
then A wins with probability
$\frac12(0.521939) + \frac12(1 - 0.521939^2)0.68233 \approx 0.50919.$
So it would seem advantageous to A to set $t_A$ low enough at
the start of the three-player game so that it is against 
B's interest to set $t_B$ to the same value or less.
But this is an awkward answer, because while there is a very
well-defined minimum value of $t_B$ that B would rationally choose,
namely, the solution of Equation $(1),$
there is no "next lower" real number.

The dominating strategy for B seems to involve
initially setting $t_B$ to the solution of Equation $(1),$
approximately $0.521939,$
so it seems that is what B will do.
Player A then has to make an arbitrary choice of some
value of $t_A$ that is smaller than this value of $t_B$;
there is no "best" value of $t_A,$
only values that are so close to $t_B$ that the
difference might be considered negligible.
Player A will shoot first, and B and C will then set
both $t_B$ and $t_C$ equal to the solution of
$t^2 + t^3 = 1,$ approximately $0.75488.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I define a strategy $x'$ for player A such that $x'$ converges to $t_{B} = 0.521939$ from below, can i say that the strategy set $(x',t_{B},t_{C})$ forms a Nash equilibrium? (with $t_{C} \geq 0.569842$)

Also can you consider firing at $t_{0} = 0.507$ optimal for player A? $t_{0}$ is the time such that $t = (1-t^2) * 0.682$. By definition an optimal strategy is a strategy that minimizes ones maximum loss an oppenent can do, or am I wrong?

Comment: Since (other than events of zero probability) there are only three outcomes of the three-player game--A wins, B wins, or C wins--and A loses just as much in either of the cases where B wins or C wins, minimizing loss for A is the same as maximizing A's chance to win. The formula $t = (1-t^2)\times 0.682$ would be the best time for A to choose if A was choosing both $t_A$ and $t_B$ and had to make them equal; but B chooses $t_B$ and has a reason to choose a later time. You were right that $t_A\approx0.507$ is not an equilibrium.